# Two-dimensional heat transfer in Matlab

Tags: numerical-methods, finite-differences

I am given a problem where the heat in a rectangular $8\times8$ plate has to be computed using Matlab.  The PDE governing this question is $-\nabla\cdot(k\nabla T)=f$ where $k$ and $f$ are scalar functions in terms of $x$ and $y$ and $T(x,y)$ represents the temperature of the plate at a given point.

My first task is to write the finite difference scheme of $\nabla\cdot(k\nabla T)$ at a point $(x_i,y_j)$ which leads to suggesting a system of equations that approximate the solution to the BVP (BC are $T=0$ everywhere).

For my finite difference scheme I end up with the following equation:
$$ \nabla\cdot(k\nabla T)=  
k(x_i,y_j ) \frac{T_{i+1,j}+T_{i-1,j}-2T_{i,j}}{\Delta x} +   
k_x (x_i,y_j ) \frac{T_{i+1,j}-T_{i,j}}{\Delta x} +  
k_y (x_i,y_j ) \frac{T_{i+1,j}-T_{i,j}}{\Delta y} +  
k(x_i,y_j ) \frac{T_{i,j+1}+T_{i,j-1}-2T_{i,j}}{\Delta y} $$

I can't seem to figure out how to get my system of equations and I feel like it might be because my finite difference scheme is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your discretization of $\nabla \cdot (k \nabla T)$ is incorrect.  An immediate correction is to replace $\Delta x$ and $\Delta y$ in the 2nd & 5th lines with $(\Delta x)^2$ and $(\Delta y)^2$ -- in other words,

\begin{align*}
(\nabla \cdot (k \nabla T))_{i,j} &= k(x_i, y_j) \frac{T_{i+1,j} + T_{i-1,j} - 2T_{i,j}}{(\Delta x)^2} + k_x(x_i, y_j) \frac{T_{i+1,j} - T_{i,j}}{\Delta x} \\
& \qquad \cdots + k_y(x_i, y_j) \frac{T_{i,j+1} - T_{i,j}}{\Delta y} + k(x_i, y_j) \frac{T_{i,j+1} + T_{i,j-1} - 2T_{i,j}}{(\Delta y)^2}. \tag{*}
\end{align*}

Note, however, that $\frac{T_{i+1,j} + T_{i-1,j} - 2T_{i,j}}{(\Delta x)^2}$ is a second-order accurate approximation of $T_{xx}$, while $\frac{T_{i+1,j} - T_{i,j}}{\Delta x}$ is only a first-order accurate approximation of $T_x$. Therefore, a numerical scheme based on (*) can be expected to have at most first-order accuracy (in the $L^\infty$ norm) in general.  **For a second-order accurate discretization, see ($\dagger$) at the end.**  In order to motivate it, however, let's focus on 1D, where $\nabla \cdot (k \nabla T) = (k T_x)_x$.

A second-order discretization of $(k T_x)_x$ is 
\begin{align*}
((k T_x)_x)_i &= \frac{k(x_{i+1/2}) (u_x)_{i+1/2} - k(x_{i-1/2}) (u_x)_{i-1/2}}{2(h/2)} \tag{1} \\
&= \frac{k(x_{i+1/2}) \frac{u_{i+1} - u_i}{2(h/2)} - k(x_{i-1/2}) \frac{u_i - u_{i-1}}{h}}{2(h/2)}, \tag{2}
\end{align*}
which reduces to
\begin{align*}
(\nabla \cdot (k \nabla T))_i &= \frac{k(x_{i+1/2}) u_{i+1} + k(x_{i-1/2}) u_{i-1} - (k(x_{i+1/2}) + k(x_{i-1/2})) u_i}{h^2}, \tag{3}
\end{align*}
with $x_{i+1/2} = \frac12 (x_i + x_{i+1})$.

How did this calculation work?

- The right-hand side of (1) is simply the central finite difference (FD) discretization of $\nu_x$ where $\nu = kT_x$.  *In contrast with the forward- or backward- FD discretizations of $\nu_x$, which are first-order accurate, a central FD discretization of $\nu_x$ is second-order accurate.*
- Equation (2) is a repeat -- it's the central FD discretization of $u_x$.
- Intuitively, since we've used second-order accurate approximation, we might claim that (3) is second-order accurate -- *one can prove that this is true, for example, by computing the local truncation error*.
- Note: The denominators of (1) and (2) involve "$2(h/2)$" -- rather than $h$ -- since the denominator (of the central FD discretization of $\nu_x$ or $u_x$) is $= 2\times\text{step size}$, where -- in this case -- $\text{step size} = h/2$.

Equation (3) is easily extended to 2D in a direction-by-direction manner, e.g., 
\begin{align*}
(\nabla \cdot (k \nabla T))_{i,j} &= \frac{k(x_{i+1/2,j}) u_{i+1,j} + k(x_{i-1/2,j}) u_{i-1,j} - (k(x_{i+1/2,j}) + k(x_{i-1/2,j})) u_{i,j}}{h^2} \\
& \qquad \cdots + \frac{k(x_{i,j+1/2}) u_{i,j+1} + k(x_{i,j-1/2}) u_{i,j-1} - (k(x_{i,j+1/2}) + k(x_{i,j-1/2})) u_{i,j}}{h^2}, \tag{$\dagger$}
\end{align*}
with $x_{i+1/2,j}$, $x_{i,j+1/2}$, etc., defined analogously.